# Why do my three javascript functions work properly separately, but they break when they are together?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, passwords

I am learning javascript.

I have been tasked with the following:

A username and password form validation that has three functions.

1. validateInput() verifies that the inputs are not empty (not using "required" in the html tag).
2. isPasswordValid() verifies that the password is atleast 8 characters, has a numver, a special character, a lower case and an upper case. **If any of these fail, the fields are cleared and the user is asked to re-enter a new password**
3. isPasswordStrong() verifies if the password contains 3 or more of the same characters as the username. **If THIS fails, a text should appear beneath the inputs and tell the user "Password can't contain more than 3 charactes from the username."**

**Problem:**
When I check the functions independently, they all work great, but when I ask the form to check all three at the same time then the error message related to function3 does not display itself and the page just reloads.

**What I have tried:**
-> Nesting all three functions in another function, this just made it go even more crazy

Can someone help please. Below are snippets of both my html and my js documents:

HERE IS THE CODE FROM THE HTML DOCUMENT

```
  <form id="login-form" action="" method="post" 
        onsubmit="return (validateInput() & isPasswordValid() & isPasswordStrong())"> 
        <fieldset class="validator">
            <legend>Password Validator</legend>
            <table class="fields-table">
              <tr id="topRow">
                <td>
                  <label for="username"><h4 class="label">Username</h4></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <label for="password"><h4 class="label">Password</h4></label>
                </td>
                <td></td>   <!--blank box-->
              </tr>
              <tr id="fields">
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
                  placeholder="Username">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name="password" id="password"
                  placeholder="Password">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button type="submit" class="submit">Validate</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="note">
                <td colspan="3">
                  <p id="error-length"></p>
                  <p id="error-number"></p>
                  <p id="error-special"></p>
                  <p id="error-lower"></p>
                  <p id="error-upper"></p>
                  <p id="error-password"></p>
                  <p id="error-similar"></p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

NOW HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT FOR THE JS DOCUMENT

```
//      Verify the input types are non-empty
function validateInput() {
    var user = document.getElementById('username')
    var pass = document.getElementById('password');
    
    if (user.value == '' || user.value == null) {
        console.log('username field empty');
        alert('Username is required');
    } else

    if (pass.value == '' || pass.value == null) {
        console.log('password field empty');
        alert('Password is required');
    }
}

//      Verify that the password requirements are met by 
//      employing pattern matching on the password entered
//  -> must be minimum eight characters long
//  -> must contain at least one number
//  -> must contain one special character
//  -> must contain one lower case character
//  -> must contain one upper case character
function isPasswordValid() {
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;

    //  Nested Function that checks: At least 8 chars long?
    function checkLength() {
        for (var i=0; i < pass.length; i++) {
            if (pass.length >= 8) {
              return true;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("error-length").innerHTML 
        = "Password must be 8 or more characters.";
        return false;
    }
    if (checkLength()) console.log('Password is 8 or more characters.');
    if (!checkLength()) console.log('Password is less than 8 characters');

    //  Nested Function that checks: Has Numbers?
    function checkNumbers() {
        var numbers = "0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (pass[i] === numbers[j]) return true;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("error-number").innerHTML 
        = "Password requires a number.";
        return false;
    }
    if (checkNumbers()) console.log('Password contains a number.');
    if (!checkNumbers()) console.log('Password does not contain a number');

    //  Nested Function that checks: Has Special Character?
    function checkSpecialChars() {
        var specialChars = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";
        for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < specialChars.length; j++) {
                if (pass[i] === specialChars[j]) return true;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("error-special").innerHTML 
        = "Password requires a special character.";
        return false;
    }
    if (checkSpecialChars()) console.log('Password contains a special character.');
    if (!checkSpecialChars()) console.log('Password does not contain a special character.');

    //  Nested Function that checks: Has Lower Case?
    function checkLowerCase() {
        for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
            if (pass[i] === pass[i].toLowerCase()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("error-lower").innerHTML 
        = "Password requires a lower case.";
        return false;
    }
    if (checkLowerCase()) console.log('Password contains a lower case.');
    if (!checkLowerCase()) console.log('Password does not contain a lower case.');

    //  Nested Function that checks: Has Upper Case?
    function checkUpperCase() {
        for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
            if (pass[i] === pass[i].toUpperCase()) {
                console.log(pass[i]);
                return true;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("error-upper").innerHTML 
        = "Password requires an upper case.";
        return false;
    }
    if (checkUpperCase()) console.log('Password contains an upper case.');
    if (!checkUpperCase()) console.log('Password does not contain an upper case');

    //  Check all functions and if any return false then 
    //  password is not valid, clears inputs.

    if (!checkLength() || !checkNumbers() || !checkSpecialChars() ||
        !checkLowerCase() || !checkUpperCase()) {
        // alert('Password is not valid! Please enter a new password');
        return false;
    }
}

//      Make sure that entered password doesn’t contain
//      more than three characters from the username
function isPasswordStrong() {
    var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var x = 0;

    console.log('the password entered is: ' + pass);
    console.log('the username entered is: ' + user);

    for (var i=0; i < user.length; i++) {
        if (pass.includes(user[i])) {
            x++;
        }
    }
    console.log('user and pass have ' + x + ' chars in common.');
    if (x >= 3) {
        document.getElementById("error-similar").innerHTML 
        = "Password can't contain more than 3 charactes from the username.";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `validateInput() && isPasswordValid() && isPasswordStrong()`, a single `&` means something different in Javascript.

Comment: From experimenting, it seems like & is evaluating both sides of the argument but when I put && it evaluates only the left and when that is true it does not evaluate the right. But that means that the password can have all the right kinds of characters but contain 3 from username and it still goes through

Comment: Ah I see, this is a separate mistake: You do not `return true` in all three validation functions, so the actual return value is `undefined`, which is falsy (evaluates to `false`). Therefore, the chain with `&&` is short-circuited after the first validator and ends.

Comment: I see! Would that also be why the page was reloading every? 

I added return true for the areas that were missing it:

```
function isPasswordValid() {
...
    if (!checkLength() || !checkNumbers() || !checkSpecialChars() ||
        !checkLowerCase() || !checkUpperCase()) {
...;
    } else return true;
```
as well as 
```
function isPasswordStrong() {
...
    if (x >= 3) {
...
    } else return true;
}
```

But now the fields do not clear (because the page does not reload) when isPasswordValid() is false

Comment: Actually I think I just resolved that with
`       document.getElementById('password').value = '';
        document.getElementById('username').value = '';`

Comment: To reset the form better use `document.getElementById("login-form").reset();`.

Comment: I am not completely sure about reloading; actually I think it should _not_ happen when you returned `false` in the validation. However, your form is also missing the `action` attribute value, so maybe its due to that.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, php will be in our next assignment so that's probably when we will make better use of the "action" attribute of the form tag. 

For now, I was able to fix all my issues. You were a big big help, thank you!